# Write a program using integers user_num and x as input, and output user_num divided by x three times

Tags: python

Write a program using integers `user_num` and `x` as input, and output `user_num` divided by `x` three times.

Ex:

```
If the input is:
2000
2
```

Then the output is:

```
1000 500 250
```

```
Note: In Python 3, integer division discards fractions. Ex: 6 // 4 is 1 (the 0.5 is discarded).
```

Here is my code that I have:

```
user_num = int(input())
x = int(input())

for i in range(3):
    user_num/= x
    print (int(user_num), end=' ')
```

[image: Picture of my outputs v.s. theres]

I just need to add a end line with the output comes up with 250.

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

it's shockingly much simpler than y'all are making it. The program wants a straight forward answer.

```
user_num = int(input())
x = int(input())

print (user_num // x , user_num // x // x , user_num // x// x // x)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is in C but you can see the logic.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

   int userNum;
   int x;
   int ans1;
   int ans2;
   int ans3;
   
   scanf("%d", &userNum);
   scanf("%d", &x);
   
   ans1 = userNum/x;
   ans2 = ans1/x;
   ans3 = ans2/x;
   
   printf("%d %d %d\n", ans1, ans2, ans3); 

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
''' Type your code here. '''
user_num = int(input()) 
x = int (input())
 
i = 0
while i <= 2 :
    if i <= 1:
        user_num //= x
        print(user_num, end= " ")
        i += 1
    elif i == 2:
        user_num //= x
        print(user_num)
        i += 1
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
user_num = int(input())
x = int(input())
soln = (user_num / x) 
print(int(soln), end=' ')
user_num = (soln / x)
print(int(user_num), end=' ')
user_num = (user_num / x)
print(int(user_num))
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

This should work just fine

```
user_num = int(input())
x = int(input())

results = []
for i in range(3):
    user_num/= x
    results.append(str(int(user_num)))
print(' '.join(results))
```

Comment: The second one worked and didn't have a unneeded space at the end the first one had in unneeded space at the end.

Answer (score -2):

```
user_num = int(input())

x = int(input())

    user_num1 = user_num // x
    user_num2 = user_num1 // x
    user_num3 = user_num2 // x

print(user_num1, user_num2, user_num3)
```

Comment: Please include a description along with your code, rather than just posting code.